# How to show $A\subset B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ are two non-empty sets.

We know that to prove $A=B$, we show $A\subset B$ and $A\supset B$. To prove $A\subset B$, we argue if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$. Similar for $A\supset B$.

---

Now suppose we want to prove that $A\subset B$. Then first we argue if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$. Then **do we have to show** that $\exists x_0\in B$, such that we do **NOT** have $x_0\in A$ ?

**Note:** If this has been asked before, please let me know, I will delete this post then.

Comment: Why would we have to show this, if you only want to prove $A$ is contained in $B$?

Comment: So I was reading this theorem: $X,Y$ are two topological space, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$, to show $f$ continuous, then for every subset $A$ of $X$, one has $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{(f(A))}$ Here the author did not show the other side. But I thought that to complete the proof one need to show other side. But As you are telling now I think it is not.

Comment: For the case you have in mind, the reverse inclusion is false in general, as it would imply the image of a closed subset is closed, which is not true in general (unless the closed subset is compact).. There's even a name for continuous maps having this property: `closed maps`.

Comment: @Bernard by "the other side", I mean $\exists x_0\in B$, such that $x_0\notin A$. But I don't think it is needed anyway, since here $\subset$ does not imply **proper subset**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that two sets are equal all you need to show is that each is included in the other. This is due to axiom of extensionality. However in case it happens that $A\subset B$ and $\exists x\in B:x\notin A$ then you can stop right here and conclude that the two sets are not equal for if they were equal then any member of $B$ would be a member of $A$.

Still and all there are instances where you need to prove that $A$ is properly contained in $B$ where you showthat $A\subset B$ and $\exists x\in B:x\notin A$ which is plainly a different scenario and it doesn't have to do anything with proving a *set equality.*

It is also possible that you meant proper inclusion by the symbol $\subset$, and in that case you are right and we do have to show that $\exists x\in B:x\notin A$. Note that in the previous paragraphs I denote *normal set inclusion* by $\subset$ i.e. $A\subset B \iff \forall x(x\in A\implies x\in B)$.

Comment: So I was reading this theorem: $X,Y$ are two topological space, and $f:X\rightarrow Y$, to show $f$ continuous, then for every subset $A$ of $X$, one has $f(\bar{A})\subset \overline{(f(A))}$ Here the author did not show the other side. But I thought that to complete the proof one need to show other side. But as you said here $\subset$ does not refer to proper subset, so we do not need to show that.

Comment: You actually don't need the other side. $\forall A\subset X: f(\overline A)\subset \overline {f(A)}$ is a characterization of continuity of $f$. Here $\subset$ is just set-inclusion. But it is better to use $\subseteq$ to denote set inclusion while $\subsetneq$ to proper set inclusion.

Comment: Thanks, I understood.

Answer (score 2):

It may depend on a context, if $\subset$ is meant as  $\subsetneq$, then you have to show that there is such a $x_0$.

But from your question it seems that you treat $\subset$ as $\subseteq$, so in this context, you dont have to show that.

Answer (score 0):

No. We only would have to do that if we intended to prove that $A\varsubsetneq B$.